# CoreWebView2Ready cs1061 error - trying to enable Youtube native fullscreen into winform

Tags: c#, error-handling

As the title says, I am getting an error for CoreWebView2Ready (Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1061  'WebView2' does not contain a definition for 'CoreWebView2Ready' and no accessible extension method 'CoreWebView2Ready' accepting a first argument of type 'WebView2' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  Cosmos.Desktop  C:\Code\Cosmos\Cosmos.Desktop\Views\HowToGuide\ViewSites\HowToViewSites.cs  32  Active
)

and I do not know how to fix it.

```
private async void InitializeWebView2()
{

            webView21 = new WebView2();            
    
            await webView21.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(null);
            webView21.CoreWebView2.Settings.IsWebMessageEnabled = true;
    
            
            string youtubeVideoId = "VideoID";
            string youtubeVideoQuality = "hd720";
            string youtubeVideoUrl = $"https://www.youtube.com/embed/{youtubeVideoId}?vq={youtubeVideoQuality}";
    
            webView21.CoreWebView2Ready += WebView21_CoreWebView2Ready;
            webView21.CoreWebView2.Navigate(youtubeVideoUrl);
    
            Controls.Add(webView21);
}
```

Thank you, very much appreciated.

I was hoping for it to work. Relatively new to coding.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/

Comment: Thank you, you've made me a better Software Developer!

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, `CoreWebView2Ready` doesn't exist on `WebView2`. [Checking docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.winforms.webview2?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.1938.49) (which is the first thing you should do), nothing named like it exists is in there either.

I found a similar event named `CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted` on that same page. When you choose an older version of .NET in the docs, you see that the "Ready" method does exist on there; it was likely renamed and you are following an old tutorial.